# Не устанавливается pyqt5-tools

Tags: python, pyqt5, pip, install

Никак не могу понять в чем проблема, не устанавливается pyqt5-tools.

CMD выдает в конце:

> ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package
> pip._vendor.distlib

Comment: Возможно, нужно переустановить pip, попробуйте: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64451272/5909792

Comment: вроде разобрался, нужно было обновить pip